# Edit Static User in Spring Security

Tags: spring, security

I have a java app written by a developer. The app is using Spring Security and uses static usernames and passwords. I'm trying to find where the usernames are stored so that I can add new users and remove old ones.

I'm using Eclipse IDE to view the source code. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Things may seem clearer if you could add some codes.

Comment: This is not reproducible for us → we cannot help you. Please read the ["How do I ask?" Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes, apologies. I'm not a developer so let me know what would be helpful and I'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

Search after a class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` (so basically search after this string in code). Look over the file you have found. Either there are your credentials directly, or post the content you find there.

Answer (score 0):

In spring-security chances of having static user credentials are:

In application property file

```
spring.security.user.name=
spring.security.user.password=
```

In configure method of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extended class:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("USERNAME")
            .password("USERPASSWORD");
 }
```

this are two ways of creating static users.